# What places to give out

Tags: python

I just started learning python, and I'm trying to write code that prints out which places the contestants in a competition will get. There will only be 3 values and you can see what I've done below;

```
s1 = input('Score 1: ')
s2 = input('Score 2: ')
s3 = input('Score 3: ')

if s1 != s2 and s2 != s3 and s3 != s1:
  print('1st 2nd 3rd')
elif s1 == s2 and s2 == s3 and s3 == s1:
  print('1st 1st 1st')
```

As you can see, I just need to find, depending on the user's input, what places are given (i.e. 1st 2nd or 3rd). How would I go about finding if the places given are '1st 1st 3rd' or '1st, 2nd, 2nd'? The higher the points the higher place you receive.

Edit: Sorry, was unclear before, but was just wondering for example if I had values 10, 10 and 5, it should print '1st 1st 3rd' and if the values were 10, 5 and 5, it should print '1st 2nd 2nd'.
How should I go about doing this?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def ranking(num=3):
    scores = []
    for n in range(num):
        msg = 'Score %d' % (n+1)
        scores.append((msg, input('%s: ' % msg)))
    scores.sort(key=lambda rank: rank[1], reverse=True)
    return scores

>>> X = ranking(3)
Score 1: 4
Score 2: 5
Score 3: 8
>>> print X
[('Score 3', 8), ('Score 2', 5), ('Score 1', 4)]

>>> def num2ord(n):         
    return '%dxx' % n #TODO

>>> ppos, pscore = None, None
>>> for pos, (msg, score) in enumerate(X):
    if score != pscore:
        ppos = pos
    pscore = score
    print '%s is %d' % (num2ord(ppos+1), msg)

1xx is Score 2
1xx is Score 3
3xx is SCore 1
```

The function num2ord could be taken from [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576888-format-a-number-as-an-ordinal/)